# Two web apps under the same Azure Web App

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an ASP.NET Core SPA app that requires authentication. I also want to have a single static public HTML page for unauthenticated users.

I'd like to set these up like this:

Public HTML page => https://example.com
SPA app => https://member.example.com

Can I do this using a single web app on Azure App Service or do I need two separate web apps?

Comment: I will suggest you have a look at this article https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tomholl/2014/09/21/deploying-multiple-virtual-directories-to-a-single-azure-website/

Comment: This definitely seems to describe my scenario. I think the separate apps would run under same host and same domain though, correct? Meaning `https://example.com` for the public page and `https://example.com/member/` for the secured app. Is that right?

Comment: yes, the concept runs like parent and child app

Comment: Is there a reason you want these on the same App Service? You pay for the App Service Plan, which can have many App Services for the same price.

Comment: Maybe I'm not clear about the plans. For me to have both example.com and member. example.com, I need two separate web apps which would cost me extra money - I think. Then, there's the SSL matter where if I have two separate web apps on Azure, I either need an SSL that supports multiple hosts under the same domain or buy an additional SSL for the member.example.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since other communities have provided suggestions, I just summarized the existing approaches and my ideas for you to achieve your purpose:

- Use [multiple virtual directories](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tomholl/2014/09/21/deploying-multiple-virtual-directories-to-a-single-azure-website/) under a single web app as Zahid Faroq commented
- Use two separate web apps

  Since you are using azure web app, for a simple way, you could leverage [App Service Certificate](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/internals-of-app-service-certificate/), and choose the **S1 Standard** certificate SKU which could create SSL bindings for root and www subdomain. Example: A single certificate could be used to protect `example.com` and `www.example.com`. If you use other subdomain instead of www and you could confirm that you only need two SSL certificates, then you need to buy an additional SSL for `member.example.com`. Also, you could check [WoTrus TLS / SSL Certificates](https://store.wotrus.com/), [GoDaddy SSL Certificates](https://www.godaddy.com/web-security/ssl-certificate), [How to get FREE SSL Certificate for Website (HTTPS)](https://geekflare.com/free-ssl-tls-certificate/).